# Convolutional Neural Networks trained with vital data eg. EKG?

Tags: dataset, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am wondering if CNN are a right tool for classification of human vital data. My data base consists of vector measurements and has a dimension of

$$ \mathsf{3000 \times 1 \times  1 \times  numberOfSamples}$$

My concern is that data units are so low dimensional that resourcing to deep learning techniques is pointless. On the other hand our team tried before many other machine learning alorithms but without success. Maybe somebody wants to share their opinion and possibly a suggestion regarding network architecture and hyper parameters.

Comment: This is very broad, and probably not answerable in its present form. Can you narrow this down from "somebody wants to share their opinion"?

Comment: Well, I mean is it possible to train a cnn using only ekg vector measurments and if so what would be a suitable architecture ?

Comment: @jojo That sounds like a research question to me. Why don't you try some alternative models and report back your findings here?

Comment: Well this is what I am currently working on, I asked in case anybody could give me a hint. In any case I can keep you posted :)

Comment: Could you give an example of the type of data that you wish to classify. The dimensionality is less interesting than the factors. How many time-series and how much data (length = sample rate x samples) do you have per subject? What hypothesis do you have for your classification or will you be using an explorative approach?

Comment: Convolutionals might turn out to be the right tool for this job, but their main application to date has been in imaging. This isn't surprising, given that the receptive regions that serve as one of its distinguishing marks were inspired by the structure of optic nerves (specifically cat eyes at first, I think). I'm wondering if an explicitly time-dependent family of algorithms like spiking or echo state networks might be more suitable for this? Time structures, phases, waves etc. are mentioned far more often in the literature on those methods. Just a thought.

Comment: @noumenal I wish to classify 15sec overlapping ekg signals taken from a 50 min survey, i separated a cluster of people having similar reaction and want to classify to classes first- ekg signal while the person was being instructed/explained a task, second- during the task, there is approximately twice as much data of class 1 as of class 2. There is a similar paper http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7318926 but what surprises me they dont use any relu, bnorm or dropout layers in their network.

Comment: @SQLServerSteve yes, but other methods have failed us so far. The hope is that magic tool - CNN will somehow detect what we couldn't.

Comment: @jojo Have you tried spiking or echo state networks yet to solve this problem? I'm just curious since I'm doing  a lot of reading on these topics right now. So far I haven't run into any case studies of them being used in EKG analysis, but that doesn't mean there aren't any out there. They're both fairly recent technologies so the academic papers are still more focused on theory than applications. I doubt that convolutionals will be useful for this, since  filtering by receptive regions breaks down in information in a granular way that is well-suited to spatial but not temporal analysis.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that's useful for analysis of time series like this is to explicitly break out the frequency dependent features, rather than trusting that your model will discover them. Do a [wavelet transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet_transform) and you'll quickly get both enough data that deep learning is sensible *and* you'll expose a number of useful features for the model.

I am not yet aware of papers investigating what sort of masks are most useful for CNNs on wavelet data, but I haven't looked. You might be able to find some prior work.